# Kafka on docker swarm not working after a while

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, docker-swarm, swarm

I'm using `Kafka` in a `swarm` environment.

I have been encountered that Kafka's logs show nothing and it seems everything is okay, but when you consume from a topic, get nothing from the broker.

This happens suddenly and I don't see anything from the log.

Comment: Before anything, Please check the group consumer and confirmed that there is no active consumer on that! you can only have numbers of consumers equal to the number of partitions that you have in default consumer policy. you can check it with the `kafka-consumer-groups`

Comment: Set the log level to debug and see the log files. with current information, it's hard to figure out the problem.